# Latex: How to draw an equilibrium arrow with overpic?

Tags: overpic

Does anybody know how to draw an equilibrium arrow with overpic (into a picture)?

With equilibrium arrow I mean the arrows in a chemical equilibrium equation:

[image: equilibrium equation]

In the code I would like to put an equlibrium arrow, where  %\put(30,11)\ce{<=>} stands.

[image]

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headsepline,liststotoc,bibtotoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}


\linespread{1.07616} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}


\usepackage[top=3cm, left=3.0cm,right=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}


\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\setcapwidth[c]{.8\textwidth}
\setcapindent{0pt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\usepackage{units}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Schriftbild
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % ein neuer Paragraph hat keinen Einzug in der ersten Zeile
\setlength{\parskip}{6 pt}

% Overpic dient der nachträglichen Beschriftung von Grafiken in der gewählten Schriftart von Latex
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage[
pdftitle={Titel},
pdfsubject={Thema},
pdfauthor={Autor},
pdfkeywords={Schluesselwoerter}
]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\C}{$^\circ \text{C}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{overpic}[width=0.4\textwidth, grid,tics=5
        ]
        {GEH_Oberfl_neu.png}
        \put(11,10){OH\textsubscript{2}\textsuperscript{+}}
        %\put(30,11)\ce{<=>}
        \put(44,10){OH}
        %   \put(11,10){p}
        \put(77,10){O\textsuperscript{-}}
    \end{overpic}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from. Also, what is an "equilibrium arrow"?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the tipps! I changed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headsepline,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{overpic}[width=0.4\textwidth, grid,tics=5]{example-image}
        \put(11,10){\parbox{0.4\textwidth }{\ce{OH2+ <=> OH}}}
        \put(77,10){O\textsuperscript{-}}
    \end{overpic}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have enclosed the `\ce{}` command from `mhchem` in a parbox, so it is displayed correctly using `overpic`. The result is shown in the following image:

[image]

Please note that I have deleted packages and commands that are not nessesary for the MWE. Additionally, I have replaced the deprecated class options `liststotoc` and `bibtotoc` by their up to date replacements `listof=totoc` and `bibliography=totoc` respectively.